# Magento 1.9 URL rewrite reverts default system URL after re-indexing

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I have a problem in Magento 1.9. I have created catalogs and rewrite it to display custom page and product. The rewrites are successful however after re-indexing the default system URL were shown.

These are my steps in URL re-writing:

a. Delete old system URL.

b. Create new URL re-write by selecting custom in the drop-down box.

c. Fill out necessary fields and save.

d. Refresh Magento cache.

The problem is that when I try to re-index, the system URL reverts back. 
My question is why is it that the old system URL reverts back? and how can i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL for the product or the category is what you have set for it in the **url key** of the product or category.

Everytime you reindex Magento creates a rewrite for the specified url key.

If you need to change that URL then you need to change the url key in the product or category edit screen.

If you **insist** on using the rewrite route, then don't delete the system rewrite, instead create a new rewrite from the system rewrite to your desired URL. But don't this is kind of backwards, just set the url key and you'll be fine.